# Reverse the effect of endianness on a memory dump

Tags: text-processing, hex

I've got a series of pipe commands that gets me a memory dump represented as a string of hexadecimal. This memory dump includes some ascii text that I want to read. The endianness of the memory dump means that whenever I pipe it to `xxd -p -r`, I get groups of 4 characters that occur sequentially, but where the characters within each group occur in reverse order. I'm looking for `<something>` that would undo that order.

For example, `<something>` would do:

```bsh
$ echo "lleHoW o!dlr" | <something>
Hello World!
```

or

```bsh
$ echo "43218765" | <something>
12345678
```

Comment: I think `xxd` has a flag to change endianness.

Comment: unfortunately it won't work with `-r -p`: _-e Switch to little-endian hexdump. This option treats byte groups as words in little-endian byte order. The default grouping of 4  bytes may be changed using -g.  This option only applies to hex- dump, leaving the ASCII (or EBCDIC)  representation  unchanged. **The command line switches -r, -p, -i do not work with this mode.**_

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple regex-based rewrite.

```
sed 's/\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)\(.\)/\4\3\2\1/g'
```

(For changing endianness, you could convert your hex dump to binary data with `xxd -r`, swap the endianness, then take a hex dump. But that wouldn't swap the two hex digits in a byte, which I don't think xxd supports.)